# HTTP redirect in websocket (play framework)

Tags: playframework, websocket, playframework-2.0

I am following the following tutorial to construct a websocket: http://blueprintforge.com/blog/2012/02/13/websockets-in-play-2-dot-0

It works for me. However, I would like to use the websocket to show the progress of a form submission/job. After my job is done running, I want to redirect the user to a static url.

In play framework, you can return

```
WebSocket<String>
```

instead of

```
Result
```

But result will let you redirect by returning redirect('www.domain.com/job8273')

Is this possible to redirect using websockets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain an upload finished message and redirect with JavaScript:

```
websocket.onmessage = function(evt){
    if(evt.data=="finished") 
      window.location.href = 'www.domain.com/job8273';
}
```

Comment: I've considered this already. Problem is, my jobid is generated in the backend (server side) Java, not in Javascript. I've considered setting the attribute of a DIV or some element with the job id when im done, then use the value of that attribute in javascript to redirect. But I dont think that is a good way to do it

Comment: so you just send the id in the message.